# Why is it called a tricorder?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9

> The device is square, the readout is square, maybe it should be called square-corder.

Did the original tricorder only have 3 functions?

I checked the [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tricorder) entry but it doesn't state the *origin* of the name or any requirement that it performs 3+ functions.

Comment: Because Monocorder and Dicorder sound like a disease and death, respectively.

Comment: I always wondered how tri-ox compound worked, since, according to the partially non-canon [Starfleet Medical Reference Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_Medical_Reference_Manual), it's structure was the same as ozone.

Comment: Quadcorder, on the other hand, sounds like expensive-but-crap hi-fi equipment.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The name 'tricorder' relates to its three main *functions* (sensing, computing and recording) and is, according to the [*Star Fleet Medical Reference Manual*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Fleet_Medical_Reference_Manual), considered quasi-canon but written by [Geoffrey Mandel](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Mandel), senior production artist and designer for TNG, DS9 and Voyager, an abbreviation of the device's full name:

**"TRI**-function re**CORDER"**

[image]

This is further backed up by the reference on tricorders in the (fully canon) [Star Trek TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual)

[image]

and a similar description in the [Voyager Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_Technical_Manual)

[image]

and a similar description in the [DS9 Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_Technical_Manual)

[image]

and a similar description in the [TNG Writer's Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Writers%27_Technical_Manual)

[image]

Comment: A medical tricorder isn't quite the same as a general tricorder, it's specialized for medical readings.

Comment: @Kevin - Not true; http://oi58.tinypic.com/2mezmzb.jpg

Comment: "to which is added a specialized medical peripheral device."  And that arguably conflicts with the first text you cite, "similar in configuration to the sciences model..."

Comment: @Kevin - There's some contradiction but I suspect that's simply because the one sources is substantially later than the other (by almost 25 years) and superceded by an entirely new series...

Answer (score 27):

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricorder) entry:

> The word "tricorder" is a portmanteau of "tri-" and "recorder",
>   referring to the device's three default scanning functions: GEO
>   (geological), MET (meteorological), and BIO (biological).

I remember reading something similar in one of the early novels, but it was a long time ago.

Comment: This was also discussed and stated in "The Making of Star Trek," by Stephen E. Whitfield.  It was written after the first 2 seasons, while he had access to many of the people involved in Trek.

Comment: As of 30 seconds ago this answer is out of date. Thanks a lot, Wikipedia!

Comment: Yeah, like you can believe anything in Wikipedia..... wait...