# What functionality does a tricorder have?

Tags: star-trek, technology

I've gleaned from [a previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5873/3804) that a tricorder is named such due to it's three main scanning functions:

> The word "tricorder" is a portmanteau of "tri-" and "recorder", referring to the device's three default scanning functions: GEO (geological), MET (meteorological), and BIO (biological).

I've often joke that in a few years my smart phone will become a tricorder (it already has a magnometre, sound detector etc), but what specific functionalities does a tricorder have that allows it to scan Geo, Met and Bio signs? How close are we to getting those in a hand held device?

Comment: It has whatever functions the plot calls for.  It's the Star Trek [sonic screwdriver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_screwdriver).

Comment: Since it's never mentioned what "life signs" they're actually detecting for it's hard to say.  Currently there isn't anything that can detect electrical signals in the body at any great distance (not declassified anyway).

Comment: GEO-MET-BIO is an invention of TNG.  The word tricorder originated in TOS.

Comment: If Sam doesn't mind, I'll post that as a question.  It's always kind of bugged me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As cjm points out, there are two responses:

Out of universe, it's a plot device that allows the actors to perform certain kinds of exposition to the audience and gives the actors a prop to point around like they are doing something interesting.

In universe, there are many kinds of tricorders:
http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tricorder\
Different kinds of tricorders can detect, record and analyze (which is what I thought the original term came from) different sets of input.

-A Science tricorder seems to have the most general set of sensors and programming.  it can detect life forms, energy patterns, hazardous situations (chemicals, radiation, etc).

-A Medical tricorder is optimized to scan life forms and has a medical database of many of the known sentient beings.

-A Psycho tricorder is a specialized medical tricorder designed to do brain scanning, lie detection, mental health assessments

-A Geological tricorder/scanner has mineral, chemical and other kinds of specialized sensors to penetrate rock and dirt

-TOS and TAS even had a "heavy duty" tricorder that had longer range and more power to perform scans

-etc etc, based on the needs of the landing party (and writers)

Bonus point attempt: actually I see smartphones and pads as extensions of the data padd
http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/PADD

Comment: A comment on that bonus point:  Before it was removed from the Android Market (due to a erroneous DMCA request), there was a Tricorder app with Gravometric (accelerometer), Magnetic, Acoustic, Geographic (magnetic/GPS), Electromagnetic (network/wifi), and "Solar Activity" (retrieved from the internet) sensors.  The Future Is Now!